# Oracle sql invalid identifier with column name created with Max(case then)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to filter out just certain versions, but I get an error when I try to filter in the where clause.  How do you recommend that I filter this out?

This is my error:
ORA-00904: "APP_VER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 181 Column: 5

The query is very long, but this is an excerpt:

```
Select
prop.org,
DEVICE,
DISPLAY_TEXT,
MESSAGE_TEXT,
...
FROM
(
--history
select
SUBSTR(hist.code,1,14) as Device,
...
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'display_text' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) DISPLAY_TEXT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'message_text' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) MESSAGE_TEXT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'device.timestamp' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) DEVICE_TIMESTAMP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'alert_id' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) ALERT_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'time_stamp' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) TIME_STAMP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'error code' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) ERROR_CODE_VALUE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) APP_VER, **--this needs filtering**
    ...
from
(select  *
from 
hist_tbl
where stateId in (1.2.3)
)hist,
d_hist_tbl dmhh,
...
component_tbl cst,
...
where
(join info for the tables)
group by (list)

UNION
--current state
   substr(col,tbl,1,14) as Device,
   ...,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'display_text' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) DISPLAY_TEXT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'message_text' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) MESSAGE_TEXT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'device.timestamp' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) DEVICE_TIMESTAMP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'alert_id' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) ALERT_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'time_stamp' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) TIME_STAMP,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'error code' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) ERROR_CODE_VALUE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name' THEN D.METRICVALUE END) APP_VER, **--this needs filtering**
    ...
    from
    (select * from state_tbl
    where stateId in (1.2.3)
    
    where
    ...
) dcs,
d_metric_val_tbl dmvt,
...
component_tbl cst,
...
where
(table join info)
**and APP_VER like '%V12.0%'  --error line**
(group by list)
)result,
--Properties
(
select 
o.org,
d.did propdmdid,
dm.dcode,
dm.isactive,
...
from
...,
...,
(join info)
(group by)
)prop
where
prop.dcode = result.device
```

How can I filter just that one max case for app_ver where the version is like V12.0?

I know I'm not providing all the table info, but it's just too many tables and I'm looking for what I hope is general info.  I tried googling it but I'm not seeing anything like this. If I could add an and to the Max line for app_ver that would be great. It's also possible I'm putting the filter part for app_ver in the wrong area and not seeing it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with a **MINIMAL** and syntactically valid example of the problem along with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output for that sample data. Your code is too large, syntactically invalid and poorly formatted which makes it very difficult to debug and you have not given much idea of what you are trying to achieve or what the input is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause and include the expression and not the alias:

```sql
Select some_columns
FROM   (
  select SUBSTR(hist.code,1,14) as Device,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name'
           THEN D.METRICVALUE 
           END
         ) AS APP_VER
  from   some_tables
  group by
        SUBSTR(hist.code,1,14)
UNION
  select substr(col,tbl,1,14) as Device,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name'
           THEN D.METRICVALUE
           END
         ) AS APP_VER
  from   some_other_tables
  group by 
        substr(col,tbl,1,14)
  HAVING
        MAX(
          CASE
          WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name'
          THEN D.METRICVALUE
          END
        ) LIKE '%V12.0%'
)
```

---

Or, if you want to filter both parts of the `UNION` then filter in the outer query:

```sql
Select some_columns
FROM   (
  select SUBSTR(hist.code,1,14) as Device,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name'
           THEN D.METRICVALUE 
           END
         ) AS APP_VER
  from   some_tables
  group by
        SUBSTR(hist.code,1,14)
UNION
  select substr(col,tbl,1,14) as Device,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN METRICCODE = 'software.version.and.patch.name'
           THEN D.METRICVALUE
           END
         ) AS APP_VER
  from   some_other_tables
  group by 
        substr(col,tbl,1,14)
)
WHERE  app_ver LIKE '%V12.0%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Error you got means that there's no such column (APP_VER) in any table you're selecting data from.

I'll try to illustrate it on a simple example. This is what you have now (follow notes marked with 1, 2, 3):

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select job from       --> 2) outer subquery doesn't select DEPTNO
  3          (select job, deptno from emp where deptno = 10  --> 1) DEPTNO is here, in
  4           union all                                      -->    this (inner) subquery
  5           select job, deptno from emp where deptno = 20
  6          )
  7       )
  8  where deptno = 10  --> 3) therefore, you can't reference it here
  9  /
where deptno = 10  --> 3) therefore, you can't reference it here
      *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904: "DEPTNO": invalid identifier
```

But, if you "move" offending column so that it becomes "visible", then query works:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select job, deptno from       --> 2) outer subquery now selects DEPTNO
  3          (select job, deptno from emp where deptno = 10  --> 1) DEPTNO is here, in
  4           union all                                      -->    this (inner) subquery
  5           select job, deptno from emp where deptno = 20
  6          )
  7       )
  8  where deptno = 10  --> 3) therefore, you CAN reference it here
  9  /

JOB           DEPTNO
--------- ----------
MANAGER           10
PRESIDENT         10
CLERK             10

SQL>
```

---

Code you posted (poorly formatted, which doesn't help at all) shows a lot of subqueries (and a lot of "..." parts) so it is difficult to see what is exactly going on. I'd suggest you to start over, (sub)query by (sub)query, testing frequently and not moving on until data you get is what you expect. Then, when you include filter on APP_VER, I hope you'll do it the way Oracle expects it.